# how would I implement a counter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies, increment

```
                    //      var GAP = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 8;
            var GAP = 1000 * 10;

            var visted = $cookies.get('surveyVisitedCount');

            var timestamp = new Date().getTime();
            var oldtime = $cookies.get('surveyTimestamp');

            if(oldtime !== undefined) {
                if((timestamp - GAP) > parseInt(oldtime, 10)) {
                    // increment
                    console.log('Need to increment!');
                    // increment visits cookie, then check if it's past 3
                    if (visted < 3){
                        $cookies.put('surveyVisitedCount', visted++);
                        console.log('visted1' , visted);
                    } else {
                         //we add the banner
                        console.log('we add the banner');
                        console.log('visted2' , visted);
                    }

                }else{
                    console.log('dont need to increment');
                }
            }

            $cookies.put('surveyTimestamp', timestamp);

        }
```

I'm trying to add a banner with a counter. When the user comes to the site in a certain amount of time they are asked to fill in a survey. 
The problem is i cant seem to get the counter to ever increment. What could I be doing wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same key `surveyTimestamp` for both the timestamp and the visited count. Use different keys (say `surveyTimestamp` and `surveyVisitedCount` and you'll be good)

Comment: Ive changed it and it still comes back undefined

Answer (score 0):

There is a simpler way to implement this that I think would do what you want, without using `Date()` or cookies.

JavaScript has various timing functions, one of them being `setTimeOut()`. This repeatedly executes a function every `n` milliseconds. Using this approach, we just need to initialize the timer variable at 0 and increment it by our desired interval. For example, if we want to increment every second, and then stop when it gets to a certain value (i.e., 45 seconds):

```
var timerValue = 0; // Initialize timer to 0.
var timer;

function startTimer(timerValue) {
    var nextIncrement = function() {
        incrementTimer(timerValue);
    };
    timer = setTimeout(nextIncrement, 1000);    // Increments every second (1000 ms = 1 s)
} 

function incrementTimer(timerValue) {
    timerValue = timerValue + 1;    // This does the actual incrementing.
    startTimer(timerValue); // Pass the current timer value to startTimer for next increment.
    console.log(timerValue);    // Print values out to the console.

    // ADDED
    if (timerValue == 45) {
        clearTimeout(timer);    // Stop the timer.
        console.log("Show survey.");    // Show the survey.
    }
    // 

}

startTimer(timerValue); // Kick off the timer.
```

Comment: Im only using an increment because I set a cookie and it checks it every 15 secs to see if the value has gone up. When it gets to 3 it stops and shows a survey

Comment: You should be able to do that with the above example too. I've modified the example code to show this.